# is it possible to use gazebo with python in ros? Because all the tutorials only use cpp

Tags: gazebo, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Gazebo for making a simulation in ros. But the documentation only shows examples using c plus plus. Is it possible to use python for coding my controllers in gazebo while using it with ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140631/is-it-possible-to-use-gazebo-with-python-in-ros?-because-all-the-tutorials-only-use-cpp./) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written a simple python interface for gazebo, it may be useful for you.  (I can't post links, but google for pygazebo).

---

Originally posted by [jpieper](https://answers.ros.org/users/13636/jpieper/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-06-11**:
Is it possible to do things like getting and setting forces, velocities and positions of models, joints, etc. by using Pygazebo?

**Comment by [jpieper](https://answers.ros.org/users/13636/jpieper/) on 2014-06-11**:
I've used it to send forces and positions to joints using the default joint controller, although it is capable of any interaction which is possible over the gazebo publish subscribe bus.